# how to check word within a string using regex in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to find a exact string within a string using rexexp_like or rlike
column 1 :-'houses for rent in asher ok'
column 2:-'houses','house','rental','ok'
output should be true,false,false,true

tried below options:
regexp_like(col1, concat(col2,'.*')) -->failing for 'ok'
regexp_like(col1, concat(concat('\b,col2,'\b'))

tried rlike also, but of no use. CAN SOMEONE HELP ME

Answer (score 1):

Standard LIKE is enough:

```
SELECT *, table1.column1 ILIKE CONCAT('%', table2.column2, '%')
FROM table1
CROSS JOIN table2;
```

Output:

[image]